# Query using JOIN in document db

Tags: azure, join, azure-cosmosdb

I have multiple types of Documents in Document Db and store them with entityType to define it's Type.

I can get individual lists of entityType(s) separately and then use a query like below to get the items which already doesn't belong in second list.

```
list1.Value.Where(u => !secondList.Any(u2 => u2.ITId == u.Id)).ToList();
```

I was wondering is it possible to the same thing in Document Db using Join or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cosmos DB `JOIN` operation is limited to the scope of a single document: you join parent object with child objects under same document.

Cross-document joins are not supported, so you would have to implement such query yourself.

Comment: Yeah, the documentation says that Cosmos DB supports "inner joins". But it's not an inner-join like in SQL. It's more like a "self join".

Comment: FWIW, in the meantime they have updated the docs to say "In a relational database, joins across tables are the logical corollary to designing normalized schemas. In contrast, the SQL API uses the denormalized data model of schema-free items, which is the logical equivalent of a self-join."